# How to delete cells from UITableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want delete an object from my a `tableView` without `commitEditingStyle` like iOS Music App! I do not need a swipe to delete function! How to delete cells without `commitEditingStyle`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove an associated item which is related to a cell in your datasource, and let's assume you are removing the sixth row in the first section.

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 5, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: It's seems to works! But I need current indexPath only not anything else. Because I have more than one section and more rows as well! I have used NSFetchedResultsController class with their delegate protocol methods as well. They're works perfectly. But I do not need default deletion function from UITableView. Thanks for understanding!